# reselecting text in JTextPane after clicking other component

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I want to change the size of selected text in `JTextPane` 
but when I click `JComboBox` to select size the selection vanishes so I can't change the size. How to maintain that selection?

Comment: Hi gurpreet, if you give us more information, we should be able to help you better. Can you post the code to reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the selection remains. It's just hidden because JTextPane lost focus.

You can call `pane.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);` to make it visible and use setSelectionStart()/setSelectionEnd() to define selected fragment.